# How to remove arrow markers from the nodes that have no links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I setup a force layout in using d3.js. I defined arrow markers and attached them to links as below,

```
    container.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["end"])
        .enter().append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", String)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 30)
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 3)
        .attr("markerHeight", 3)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
        .style("fill","#999"); 

    var link = container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
        .style("stroke","#999")
        .style("fill","none")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5);
```

And my tick function is defined as,

```
    function tick(){
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });    
        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    }
```

In my network, I have some isolated nodes, i.e. those without any links. I visualized such kind of nodes in the way that the source and target of the link are both the node itself. Thus in my network, isolated nodes actually also have links in this way. What bothers me now is that, such isolated nodes are also attached by arrow markers as shown below.

[image: Example]

Does anyone have some solutions to this?

Comment: Do you have fiddle for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no man

Comment: Why do you have these dummy links with the same source and target node? Removing/filtering those would solve the problem.